# layouts for different screen sizes, why is default being picked?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have created layout files for small, large and xlarge screens sizes, but when I load my app on a Samsung S3 emulator, with the resolution of 720 x 1280 it is still the default layouts which are being used.

I do not understand why android is not using my specific layout files.

I have placed the layout files in the folders layout-large, layout-small, layout-xlarge under the folder layout.

Hope someone can point me to what I am doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: The S3 is in the "normal" category and hence uses default.

Comment: 720 x 1280 is normal? As far as I know the S2 480 x 800 is also normal, seems like a big jump in resolution for them both being normal.

Comment: no tags in subject: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 2):

The screen size buckets you are referring to are deprecated since Android 3.2 (API level 13?). If you are targeting later versions of Android then you should be using the "smallest width" qualifier to enable a finer grain control.

The Samsung Note for example will leverage the old "layout-large" bucket but it doesn't respond well to mini- or normal tablet layouts. These devices are normally running Android post 3.2 (the DELL *Streak* and original *Galaxy 10.1* tab are the exception). To differentiate in this instance supply a `layout-sw520-port` and `layout-sw520-land` resource folder and place the layouts here. Further differentiations can be made for Nexus7  type devices (sw600) and so on. Note there are reserved pixels on screen (notification/action bar etc) so the physical smallest width DPI is not precisely what your layout will respond to (albeit predictable close).

Diana Hackborn (hackbod) wrote a [comprehensive blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html?m=1) on the subject describing the motivation s behind the change and the sorts of problems (cf. Your issue) it solves. Google have also put together some advice on designing for multiple configurations as part of their tablet drive. Have an Android Dev Guide trawl should you hit further issues.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung S3 is in the "normal" category.

What I found helped me greatly to get layouts which scales to different resolutions was layout_weight="1" and layout_width="0dp", just in case someone drops by this question wondering why there layouts do not scale in some areas.